# list comprehension to filter nested python list data (json api request or converted list python)

Tags: python, json

**Hello!**

**Question:** I'm wondering how to either use a list comprehension to filter out certain results based on a word in a python list or in some other way extract only the lines I need from the list that contain a certain "key word".

**Overview:** I'm using python to make a request to an api and have received a json request. I have converted the json using json.loads() and now have a nested python list which I'm attempting to work with:

```
{"results": [
        {
            **"id": 12345678,**
            "applicant": {
                "id": 11342542,
                "first_name": "Mary",
                "last_name": "Johnson",
                "email": "mjohnson@example.org"
            },
            "average_score": 42.0,
            "collaborators": [],
            "created_at": "2020-06-02T*****",
            "current_stage": {
                "id": 5057743,
                "title": "Reviewing"
            },
            "custom_fields": [],
            "decision": null,
            **"labels": [
{
                    "id": 1124354,
                    "name": "Jerusalem"
                },
                {
                    "id": 132456,
                    "name": "Testing Stuff"
                }],**
            "notes": [
                {
                    "id": 536590,
                    "author": {
                        "id": 3342356287,
                        "first_name": "Brett",
                        "last_name": "Wallace",
                        "email": "bwallace@example.com"
                    },
                    "author_role": 2,
                    "content": "This is a sly one.",
                    "edited": false,
                    "created_at": "2020-06-03T15:28:19",
                    "is_private": false,
                    "updated_at": "2020-06-03T15:28:19"
                }
            ],
            "organization": null,
            "overall_score": 45.0,
            "program": {
                "id": 23476343,
                "name": "Test 2"
            },
        },
        {
            **"id": 112334435,**
            "applicant": {
                "id": 113560732,
                "first_name": "Steve",
                "last_name": "Henderson",
                "email": "shenderson@example.com"
            },
            "average_score": 61.0,
            "collaborators": [],
            "created_at": "2020-06-02T19:44:44",
            "current_stage": {
                "id": 549284389,
                "title": "Registration"
            },
            "custom_fields": [],
            "decision": null,
            **"labels": [
                {
                    "id": 23423,
                    "name": "Nazareth"
                },
                {
                    "id": 239843,
                    "name": "Age Requirements"
                }
            ],**
            "notes": [],
            "organization": null,
            "overall_score": 61.0,
            "program": {
                "id": 223432,
                "name": "Test 2"
            },
            "reference_id": "SPR21-2260071923",
            "state": 0,
            "status": {
                "id": 20943893,
                "name": "Accepted"
            },
            "title": "SPR21-2260071923",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-14T02:16:51",
            "weighted_score": 61.0,
            "last_submitted_at": "2020-06-03T16:44:26"
        },
}
```

I can extract just the fields I need using the following code:

```
for application in r['results']:    
    print(application['id'],application['labels'])
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
18318202 [{'id': 109135, 'name': 'Jerusalem'}, {'id': 109198, 'name': 'Testing Stuff'}]   
11233443 [{'id': 109135, 'name': 'Nazareth'}, {'id': 109198, 'name': 'Age Requirement'}]
```

Is there a way for me only return the values with "Jerusalem" in the ['labels'] field? In other words looking at the example above, it would only return the first line since the second line does not contain the word Jerusalem. I'm okay with either filtering this information from the data (conditional print statement) or extracting it to a new list, but I cannot figure out how to only get the values that contain "Jerusalem" in them. All the resources I have found talk about how to get the data loaded and converted, but not filtered out after the fact..Thanks in advance for anyone's time and support!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filtered_data = [(application['id'], application['labels']) for application in  
                 r['results'] if 'Jerusalem' in
                 (item['name'] for item in application['labels'])]
```

probably this will also work

```
filtered_data = [(application['id'], application['labels']) for application in  
                 r['results'] if application['labels'][0]['name'] == 'Jerusalem']
```

Comment: I don't know who you are, I don't know what you want...If it is money you are looking for I can tell you I don't have money, but what I do have is PRAISE and the best answer. THANK YOU so much, if I could only put into words how much you have helped me it would look more like a picture than words!! You are amazing. This worked!! I had tried something similar but did not include the item['name']. Thanks again!!

Comment: SO is not about money, it's a community. We share knowledge and help fellow coders